# Scipy Crashes on Apache Server

Tags: python, apache, scipy, nltk

I have a Python 2.7 script using NLTK that runs fine on command prompt. When I ran it in a local Apache server on the same machine, it crashes and the error log shows "NotImplementedError: cannot determine number of cpus" while loading scipy. More detailed messages are shown below. Anyone else have the same problem?

.....
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]   File "interpnd.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]   File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 95, in \r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]     from .ckdtree import *\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]   File "ckdtree.pyx", line 31, in init scipy.spatial.ckdtree\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]   File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 136, in cpu_count\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1]     raise NotImplementedError('cannot determine number of cpus')\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html
[Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1] NotImplementedError: cannot determine number of cpus\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html

Comment: OK. Solved by setting NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS.

Comment: Glad you find the solution. Please answer your question and accept it.